# Default elasticsearch configuration for docker container

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

What is the best way to configure ES index template with mappings in docker container? I expected to use template file but it seems that from version 2 it [is not possible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html). Executing http request also won't work because on container creation process doesn't start. It could be done on each container launch with script which will start ES and execute HTTP request to it but it looks really ugly.

Comment: @mavarazy, nope. I use HTTP API on containers startup

Answer (score 0):

you can configure template with mappings by execute HTTP PUT request in Linux terminal, as following:

```
curl -XPUT http://ip:port/_template/logstash -d '
    {
      "template": "logstash-*",
      "settings": {
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "number_of_shards": 8
      },
      "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
          "_all": {
            "store": false
          },
          "_source": {
            "enabled": true,
            "compress": true
          },
          "properties": {
            "_id": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "_type": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "field1": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "field2": {
              "type": "double"
            },
            "field3": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "xy": {
              "properties": {
                "x": {
                  "type": "double"
                },
                "y": {
                  "type": "double"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    '
```

The "logstash-*" is your index name, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

if using logstash, you can make template part of your logstash pipeline config

pipeline/logstash.conf

```
input {
    ...
}

filter {
    ...
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        template => "/usr/share/logstash/templates/logstash.template.json"
        template_name => "logstash"
        template_overwrite => true
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template